# How to make WSO2 EI carbon UI support Chinese

Tags: internationalization, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

How to make the interface of wso2 ei 6.5 carbon support Chinese,
I need to find the reference file about i18n and modify it into the english-chinese version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the i18n reference files related to the management console are available in this repo https://github.com/wso2/carbon-mediation. You might have to do changes in the files and build it from source to make EI carbon UI support Chinese.

Checkout the following URL for instructions related to building from source https://github.com/wso2/product-ei#building-from-source You might only have to build carbon-mediation and product-ei.

Comment: thanks , I found the file, translated it, and then packaged it. How does this jar apply

Comment: You can add the jar as a patch to the EI product. Or you can build product-ei from source. To add as a patch, go through the following documentation (In summary you have to create a 'patch9999' folder inside patches folder and paste the updated jars within that folder. Please note that you need to build the same jar version that is available in the product. For Ei 6.5.0, the relevant carbon-mediation version is 4.6.150) https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/WSO2+Patch+Application+Process